# remove only nulls values from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, null

I want to remove only nulls values not empty not 0. my array looks like this

```
[hrg_children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [col1] => 123
                                [col2] => 1
                                [col3] => 
                                [col4] => 
                                [col5] => 
                                [col6] => 
                                [col7] => 
                                [col8] => 
                                [col9] => 
                                [col10] => 
                                [col11] => 
                                [col12] => 
                                [col13] => 
                                [col14] => 
                                [hrg_lid] => 1464902183
                            )

                    )
```

Code I already tried.

```
array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $gcmArray));
```

but still fails.

Comment: Is the array you have shown in your question the `$gcmArray` you refer to in the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreach with the strict compare (`===`) or the `is_null()` function.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
   if($value === null )
      unset($array[$key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to go one level deep you can use maps and filters.

```
// Map over the first level (you're missing this bit)
$array = array_map(function ($item) {

  // Then filter the values. All values where the callback returns
  // true are returned and kept by our map. Hence the ! is_null

  return array_filter($item, function ($value) {
    return ! is_null($value);
  });
}, $array);
```

If you want to go deeper, you would need to recurse so you could use something similar to the below.

```
function recursive_unset(array $array, callable $callback) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = recursive_unset($value, $callback);
        } else {
            if ($callback($value, $key)) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

var_dump(recursive_unset($gcmArray, function ($value) {
  return is_null($value);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have used the array_filter function mistakenly.

Visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php for the documentation.

It should be something like

```
    array_filter($yourArrayToFilter, function($value) {
      return (is_null($value))? false : true;
    });
```

That means for each element of the array, if the value is null the function would return false and that element will be removed from the array.